# How can I compare 2 variables if I don't know what they are?

Tags: string, perl, numbers, comparison

If I have 2 variables `$x` and `$y` somewhere in the code flow and I don't really know if they contain numbers or string, how do I compare them?
I mean for strings we use `eq` etc while for numbers `==` or `<=` etc
Also what about greater/less etc?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know what they are, how can you ask if they're the same?

Specifically, do you consider these two to be the same?

```
"1"
"1.0"
```

Numerically, they both represent one, but stringily they contain different characters, so are different.

Answer (score 1):

greater/less for strings can be done with cmp.

```
if    ( ( $a cmp $b ) == 0 ) { print "a == b\n" }
elsif ( ( $a cmp $b )  < 0 ) { print "a  < b\n" }
elsif ( ( $a cmp $b )  > 0 ) { print "a  > b\n" }
```

To reiterate a comment above "123" cmp "56" will give less than.

So you may want to do something like this:

```
if    ( compareEm($a, $b) == 0 ) { print "a == b\n" }
elsif ( compareEm($a, $b)  < 0 ) { print "a  < b\n" }
elsif ( compareEm($a, $b)  > 0 ) { print "a  > b\n" }

sub compareEm {
    my ( $a, $b ) = @_;
    my $isnum = qr/(?=.)(?!^\.$)^[\-\+]?\d*\.?\d*$/o;
    return ( $a =~ $isnum && $b =~ $isnum ) ? $a <=> $b : $a cmp $b;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `eq`, it will always work...

Comment: What about greater/less than etc?

Comment: What does it mean "greater/less" for strings? Some lexicographic order?

Comment: In Perl there are no types, therefore you can handle all scalars as strings. For this reason greater/less will work too, but the `lt`, `gt`, etc. operators will compare them as strings. That means that "123" will be LESS than "56".

Comment: In `Scalar::Util` module you have `looks_like_number`, you can use that to check if the string is a number or not (or you can write a regexp, depending on your expectations, checking for an integer is very simple).

Comment: @glezmen:So if that function says it looks like a number does that mean that it is an integer type or a string that has only digits?

Comment: @Jim what's the difference? If you have a series of digits, you call that an integer (in real life too).
And again: in Perl there are NO SUCH THING as "integer type", since Perl is NOT a typed language. Your types are: scalar, array, hash, subroutine and references for these.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know whether your data is strings or numbers then it's usually perfectly safe to treat them as strings. If you want to treat your data as numbers, then you should probably validate the input to ensure that it is in the correct format.